# React Redux state going to init on route change with Nginx

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, redux, docker-compose

I am building an app with `React` as the front end, `Postgres` as db , `Express.js` as api and `Nginx` to manage routing. My react App uses `React-Router` and `Redux` for state management. I found that my `Redux` state was getting reset when the route changed. I guess this is because I am using `Ngnix` to route the requests and react starts up from the beginning again and without preserving the state.

I have seen examples suggesting using `Nginx` and `React` in the same `Docker` image by having two stages - a build for react and then copy the build to `Nginx` image folder in the second step. Then use this image to define a single service in docker-compose.

How will we handle this when we have API service also in the routing (which is a separate `Docker` image) ? Is there a better way of doing this (production grade)?

**Nginx conf file**

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;  
}

upstream api {
    server api:5000;  
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://client;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass  http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /api/ {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass  http://api;
    }
}
```

***docker-compose.yaml***

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: DockerFile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  client:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      dockerfile: DockerFile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    depends_on:
      - api
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: DockerFile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "3050:80"
    depends_on:
      - client
```

Comment: which router are you using? browser router, memory router, or hash router? it seems like all router would work in your environment setting. please double check did you use <Link > component instead of <a>.

Comment: I am using Browser router.

Comment: Ideally if it's a SPA, the request to get another route should not go to Nginx. It should be handled on client side

Comment: @gnujoow is probably right, sounds like some <a> which trigger the whole site to reload

Comment: Can you show your react code where how you are switching from one route to other?

Comment: @gnujoow thanks. That was the problem. Can you write it as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to go about this and it really just depends on what you're looking for. If you're saying you want production quality then you wouldn't necessarily even be hosting both the API, and serving the static files on the exact same server.

By going that route, you either have to:

- Use nginx to separate the `/api` requests and proxy your Express.js project running on a different port
- Forget about nginx and use the Express.js to also serve the static files for any request that doesn't start with `/api` (but Nginx is way better at handling static files and you don't want to occupy your Node.js process)

You'll find that many companies host their API on a separate subdomain, ex `api.twitter.com`.

If you go about it this way, you'll have much more flexibility in scalability, security, maintenance, etc. If you continue developing everything on one server, you're going to need to be load balancing much sooner and dealing with more proxying for any other services you want.

As for your Redux issue, you must be doing a normal redirection somewhere and not actually using React-Router, because React-Router uses the JavaScript `history` object to make changes to the URL path and whatnot which should never result in your Redux state being cleared.

If you want to navigate elsewhere and not use `Link` element, then you can also just `history.push("/anypathyouwant");`